# WSO2 ESB and proxy

Tags: proxy, wso2-esb

I am working with the WSO2 4.9.0 version behind a proxy and I have some troubles... For example, when I try my Web service with the option 'Try it' I have this message :

> Private proxy protocol will be attempted as cross-domain browser
>   restrictions might be enforced for this endpoint

I have tried almost everything to soluce this problem but it is still there.

I have added the options **-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxxx -Dhttp.proxyPort=xxxx** in the ***wso2server.bat*** and I have added some parameters in the axis2.ml (in 3 transportSender : HttpCoreNIOSender / PassThroughHttpSender and PassThroughHttpSSLSender ) :

```
<parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">xxxx</parameter>
<parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">xxxx</parameter>
```

Is there any other file to modify to fix this issue ?
Thank you all.

Ahhouais